# Can a program decide whether an arbitrary program halts for SOME input?

Tags: logic, computer-science, halting-problem, computability

Is there a program (may-halt? p) that can tell whether there exists an input so that (p input) halts?

I tried simple diagonalization, but it only tells me that (may-halt? diag-may-halt) must be true. It doesn't help proving whether the program exists or not.

Does such a program exist?

[image: My diagonalization]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly is the halting problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111155/what-exactly-is-the-halting-problem)

Comment: I think halting problem has the input specified, but here I want to prove the existence of such input is undecidable. Of course, I may describe an algorithm that tries all possible inputs and argues that for all inputs whether program p halts is undecidable, thus my question is undecidable. But I do not think that's a formal proof. What do u think?

Comment: You might have better luck on the [theoretical computer science stack exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, `may-halt?` doesn't exist.

(I don't think a direct proof by diagonalization would be less complex than the proof that the [Halting problem is undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem#Sketch_of_proof); otherwise *that* would be the standard example. Instead, let's reduce your problem to the Halting problem:)

Suppose there was a program `may-halt? p`, that decides if program `p` halts for *some* input. Then define:

```
halt? p x := may-halt? (\y -> if y==x then p x else ⊥)
```

where the thing in braces is a derived program. Lets break it down:

```
halt? p x := may-halt? p'
```

where `p'` is the program that (i) on input `x` computes `p x`, (ii) on any other input just loops around without terminating:

```
p' y := if y==x then p x else ⊥
```

Then `may-halt? p'` outputs true if and only if `p x` terminates.

Thus, for any program `p` and input `x`, `halt? p x` would decide if `p x` terminates. But we know that that isn't possible, so `may-halt?` doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I had a final exam this week and couldn't reply you in time. Your solution is brilliant. I didn't think I could reduce the question to the halting problem. May I ask how you came up with the thoughts ; ) Anyways, thank you very much. I understand the problem now!

Comment: But there are some programs that can be proven to halt, using [termination analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termination_analysis).