# filter hangs on infinite List

Tags: haskell

I have this code

```
isPrime x = x > 0 && filter divisible [1..x] == [1,x]
where divisible y = x `mod` y == 0

primes = filter isPrime [1..]
```

that defines an infinite List of primes.

All these cases work as Expected:

```
*Main> take 10 primes
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]

*Main> take 10 $ filter odd primes
[3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31]
```

However

```
*Main> take 10 $ filter even primes
[2
```

hangs and does not continue. I have no clue as to why... 
I restarted ghci and the problem persists. 
I'm using ghc 8.0.1.

My packages:

```
C:\projects\littlethings\prime>ghc-pkg list
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/8.0.1\lib\package.conf.d
    Cabal-1.24.0.0
    GLURaw-2.0.0.1
    GLUT-2.7.0.7
    HTTP-4000.3.3
    HUnit-1.3.1.1
    ObjectName-1.1.0.1
    OpenGL-3.0.0.2
    OpenGLRaw-3.1.0.0
    QuickCheck-2.8.2
    StateVar-1.1.0.4
    Win32-2.3.1.1
    array-0.5.1.1
    async-2.1.0
    attoparsec-0.13.0.2
    base-4.9.0.0
    binary-0.8.3.0
    bytestring-0.10.8.1
    case-insensitive-1.2.0.6
    containers-0.5.7.1
    deepseq-1.4.2.0
    directory-1.2.6.2
    fgl-5.5.2.3
    filepath-1.4.1.0
    fixed-0.2.1.1
    (ghc-8.0.1)
    ghc-boot-8.0.1
    ghc-boot-th-8.0.1
    ghc-prim-0.5.0.0
    ghci-8.0.1
    half-0.2.2.3
    hashable-1.2.4.0
    haskeline-0.7.2.3
    haskell-src-1.0.2.0
    hoopl-3.10.2.1
    hpc-0.6.0.3
    hscolour-1.24
    html-1.0.1.2
    integer-gmp-1.0.0.1
    mtl-2.2.1
    network-2.6.2.1
    network-uri-2.6.1.0
    parallel-3.2.1.0
    parsec-3.1.9
    pretty-1.1.3.3
    primitive-0.6.1.0
    process-1.4.2.0
    random-1.1
    regex-base-0.93.2
    regex-compat-0.95.1
    regex-posix-0.95.2
    rts-1.0
    scientific-0.3.4.6
    split-0.2.3
    stm-2.4.4.1
    syb-0.6
    template-haskell-2.11.0.0
    text-1.2.2.1
    tf-random-0.5
    time-1.6.0.1
    transformers-0.5.2.0
    unordered-containers-0.2.7.0
    vector-0.11.0.0
    xhtml-3000.2.1
    zlib-0.6.1.1

C:\Users\Hamburger\AppData\Roaming\ghc\x86_64-mingw32-8.0.1\package.conf.d
    (containers-0.5.8.1)
    data-ordlist-0.4.7.0
    lazyset-0.1.0.0
    memoize-0.8.1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only 2 is prime and even. Other prime numbers aren't even. `filter` isn't smart. It tries to find the next even prime number, although it doesn't exist. That's why you have hangs.

If you want to have termination anyway, you have to understand what in general case it problem can't be solved ([halting problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111155/what-exactly-is-the-halting-problem)). But anyway you can write approximation.

For example, it's very simple approximation:

```
funnyFilter p = go ntriesMax
  where
    go _ (x:xs) | p x = x : go ntriesMax xs
    go _     []       = []
    go 0      _       = []
    go n (_:xs)       = go (n - 1) xs
    ntriesMax = 10000
```

Comment: Argh. Yes of course. Looks like a fault in my own wetware.